# Finding 3 dimensional B-spline control points from given array of points from spline solution?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, interpolation, splines

Wa are talking about [Non-uniform rational B-spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline). We have some simple 3 dimensional array like

```
{1,1,1}
{1,2,3}
{1,3,3}
{2,4,5}
{2,5,6}
{4,4,4}
```

Which are points from a plane created by some B-spline

How to find control points of spline that created that plane? (I know its a hard task because of weights that need to be calculated but I really hope it is solvable)

[image]

For those who did not got idea of question - sorry my writing is bad - we have points that are part of plane rendered here and we need to find control points that form a spline which solution is that rendered plane.

Comment: BTW: I am new here so feel free to edit my question and its tags.

Comment: Personally, I think whoever downvoted owes an explanation.  Aside from the poster's non-native English, which is eminently fixable, this doesn't strike me as a bad question.  On the other hand, I don't know enough of the words in the question to know this for sure -- hence the appropriateness of a comment accompanying a downvote.

Comment: @Ole-J, have you looked at this problem in a smaller dimensionality as a starting point? What if you had a set of points in 2-d space $L=${$(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...(x_n,y_n)$} and were trying to find a B-spline that approximated those points $L$? Do you have a way to find the (or any) B-spline that could fit those points? This seems more like a question that is appropriate for stack-overflow in the current format of the question. It's not really an interpolation problem as a "reverse-mapping" or "best-fit" problem.

Comment: @OJ: I don't understand this: "Which are points from a plane." Perhaps you didn't intend your example to be interpreted literally, but those points don't lie on a plane, not even nearly.  Maybe "plane" = "surface"?

Comment: Without fixing the number of control points before-hand, you have the problem of this being an "under-determined" set of equations, or an "over-determined" set of equations.  With enough control points, you can have an exact fit, at the expense of bizarre swings and interpolated regions. It's the same as trying to find a best-fit polynomial to a set of points: there could be no solution in the form you're looking for; there could be multiple equally good solutions; there could be an overly-good fit because you use so many terms (control points) to fit it perfectly. How did you get to this Q?

Comment: @ole-J, you could make some edits and corrections to your question based on the comments thus far, such as Joseph O'Rourke's.  What have you implemented thus far?  What led you to this question?  Have you thought about it in 2-dimensions?  Did you consider posting on stack overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a black box optimizer where the parameters are the locations and weights of the control points and the function to minimize is something like the error volume between the surfaces.

Comment: could you provide some links to articles on this black box optimizer topic?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28mathematics%29

Comment: 'the function to minimize is something like the error volume between the surfaces.' ... hm - I need and have data from 1 surface. so how can I calculate such error function?

Comment: The other surface is the NURBS surface defined by the control point locations and weights.

Comment: If your next comment is that you don't yet have the NURBS surface, then I'm going to give up and let someone else help you.

Comment: @h10:  I don't find your answer particularly helpful.  While answers on MO are not meant to be expository, I don't think it would be asking too much to expand your answer with some narration and/or background, and remove phrases like "something like" -- at least if you want your answer to be useful to anyone reading it.

Comment: @Cam-McLeman, the question is poorly formed. "Something like" may refer to the fact that there is more than one metric that could be used to minimize the error between the approximating surface define by the B-spline or NURBS-surface, and the difference in volume is one possible metric. The real problem in this question lies in the fact that the number of control points is unknown at the beginning, and a guess must be taken to start with. It's the same problem with doing k-means or fuzzy-c-means segmentation or clustering of multidimensional data: how many clusters to start with.

Comment: @h10 'error volume between the surfaces' how to compute  volume between the surfaces knowind only points from one and theoretically all points from another (but only theoretically because computing all points will be quite messy)

Answer (score 2):

What the PO actually is asking for, is how obtain the control points (or equivalently the wireframe) of a NURBS surface (the PO says "plane" instead of surface) from points *on* the surface (the black blots on the surface) that correspond to the corners of the patches on which the surface is equal to a rational parametric function.

The standard technique for obtaining the control points from surface-patches' corners is to  [Compute B-spline control points using polar forms](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0010448591900404) (unfortunately the article is behind a paywall), anyhow "**Polar Forms**" and "**Blossoming**" are the magic words to look for.